# Counting the amount of Whitespace in String

Tags: java

OK, now that I have change the `public static String` to `public static int` the last function does not print out.

Thank you all for you're help.

Here is the full program. The last function does not seem to print.

```
import java.lang.String;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class stringFuncts{

  /**
 * @param <String> <str> <Takes in a String and reverses it.>
 * @return <rev> <returns the reversed string>
 */
  public static String reverseString (String str){
    String rev = "";
    int length = str.length();

    for ( int i = length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- ){
      rev = rev + str.charAt(i);
    }
    return rev;
  }

  /**
 * @param <int> <n> <It will sum up the odds of a set number>
 * @return <results> <Will print out the total of the odds values>
 */
  public static int sumOfOdds (int n){
    int results = 0;

    for(int i = 1; i <= n*2; i += 2){
      results = results + i;
    }

    return results;
  }

  /**
 * @param <int> <blanks> <Will count the amount of whitespace in the phrase>
 * @return <numBlanks> <Will return the amount of whitespace found in the String>
 */
    public static int numberOfBlanks(String blanks){
        int numBlanks = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < blanks.length(); i++) {
         if(Character.isWhitespace(blanks.charAt(i))) 
            numBlanks++;
        }
        return numBlanks;
    }

  public static void main(String [] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str;
    int n = 0;
    String blanks;

    System.out.println("Enter a string to reverse");
    str = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("The reverse output is: " + reverseString(str));

    System.out.println("");

    System.out.println("Enter a value to sum the odds");
    n = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("The sum of the odds " + sumOfOdds(n));

    System.out.println("");

    System.out.println("Enter a string to find the amount of blanks");
    blanks = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("The number od blanks in the string is: " + numberOfBlanks(blanks));
  }
}
```

Comment: just match the string with the ASCII char of space.

Comment: @A5l-lE5 whitespace is not only space.

Comment: If i change `public static String to int`, then it does not output anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is declared as `public static String`. You're trying to return a number, so the correct declaration would be `public static int`.

Comment: If i were to change the `public static String` to `int` thier is no output.

Comment: Not to `int`, to `public static int`.

Comment: Could you please help me for second. When i run that code in a separate program, it works, but when i insert in a combine program, it is not able to print it out.

Comment: What is a "combine program"?

Answer (score 2):

In your `numberOfBlanks()` return type is  of `String` data type
change it to `int` data type

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.lang.String;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class stringFuncts{

  /**
 * @param <String> <str> <Takes in a String and reverses it.>
 * @return <rev> <returns the reversed string>
 */
  public static String reverseString (String str){
    String rev = "";
    int length = str.length();

    for ( int i = length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- ){
      rev = rev + str.charAt(i);
    }
    return rev;
  }

  /**
 * @param <int> <n> <It will sum up the odds of a set number>
 * @return <results> <Will print out the total of the odds values>
 */
  public static int sumOfOdds (int n){
    int results = 0;

    for(int i = 1; i <= n*2; i += 2){
      results = results + i;
    }

    return results;
  }

  /**
 * @param <int> <blanks> <Will count the amount of whitespace in the phrase>
 * @return <numBlanks> <Will return the amount of whitespace found in the String>
 */
    public static int numberOfBlanks(String blanks){
        int numBlanks = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < blanks.length(); i++) {
         if(Character.isWhitespace(blanks.charAt(i))) 
            numBlanks++;
        }
        return numBlanks;
    }

  public static void main(String [] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str;
    int n = 0;
    String blanks;

    System.out.println("Enter a string to reverse");
    str = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("The reverse output is: " + reverseString(str));

    System.out.println("");

    System.out.println("Enter a value to sum the odds");
    n = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("The sum of the odds " + sumOfOdds(n));

    System.out.println("");
     input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter a string to find the amount of blanks");
    blanks = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("The number od blanks in the string is: " + numberOfBlanks(blanks));
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Enter a string to reverse
this
The reverse output is: siht

Enter a value to sum the odds
3
The sum of the odds 9

Enter a string to find the amount of blanks
this is spartan!
The number od blanks in the string is: 2
```

Comment: yes I understand that the code works and prints out in a separate program, but if your where to run the new code in the post, it does not print out.

Comment: @Germblaster Hi,when i run the program on eclipse it executes well

Comment: Hi; ill re-edit to the entire program for you @Germblaster please comment:)

Comment: Btw,i still did not understand by your Oddsum function :(